# How to apply Givens rotation to a matrix with complex elements?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, rotations, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to apply [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) to a matrix, I could do it when the matrix had real values. For example, for this matrix:
$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&5\\4&1\end{bmatrix}$
I can simply calculate $sin$ and $cos$ like this:
$r=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$
$cos=3/r=0.6, sin=4/r=0.8$
But when the values are complex numbers, I have a problem in determining which value of $r$ to select. For example:
$A=\begin{bmatrix}3+1.5i&5-7i\\4-2i&1+3i\end{bmatrix}$
$r=((3+1.5i)^2+(4-2i)^2)^{0.5}=4.403-0.795i$ or $-4.403+0.795i$
So the question is, Which value of $r$ should I select? What is the criteria?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Unfortunately no, it may be a close question, but there is no satisfactory answer.

Comment: The second answer to that question gives fairly explicit instructions on how to do the complex Givens rotation.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I will inspect it and see.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I think you are right, it actually solves it.